# simple text animation in JavaScript/DHTML/canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, dhtml

Let's say I have some text as follows:

> do this, do that,
>
> then this, then that

I use CSS to add a drop shadow.

I can also use CSS to add a yellow glow behind "do this", as described here:
http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/04/make-cool-and-clever-text-effects-with-css-text-shadow/

What I want is a repeating animation:

- 1 second: make "do this" glow, everything else is drop shadow
- 1 second: make "do that" glow, everything else is drop shadow
- 1 second: make "then this" glow, everything else is drop shadow
- 1 second: make "then that" glow, everything else is drop shadow
  This should repeat on endless loop.

How do I write this animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to use:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Jevgenis Animation</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var c = -1;
          var els = new Array("el1", "el2", "el3", "el4");
          function nextEffect() {
            for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
              document.getElementById(els[i]).style.textShadow = "2px 2px #FF3333";
            c = c >= els.length - 1 ? 0 : c + 1;
            var e = document.getElementById(els[c]);
            e.style.textShadow = "0 0 3px #FF3333";
          }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
          .shadow { text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF3333 }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body onload="setInterval('nextEffect()', 1000);">
        <span id="el1" class="shadow">do this</span>
        <span id="el2" class="shadow">do that</span>
        <span id="el3" class="shadow">then this</span>
        <span id="el4" class="shadow">then that</span>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Tested it, works fine in FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari.

For IE, you should probably implement something similar:

```
el1 { filter:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#666666,direction=45)
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=#bbbbbb,Strength=2)
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.blur(pixelradius=5, enabled='true')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I approached this:

You can make a variable `var animStep = 0`, then use a self-repeating function, like `ANIMATE` to check and increment `animStep`, which acts to track the state of animation.

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
Animate 4 Frames{
    Frame 1: Do this glows, and everything else has a shadow
    Frame 2: Do that glows, and everything else has a shadow
    Frame 3: Then this glows, and everything else has a shadow
    Frame 4: Then that glows, and everything else has a shadow
}
```

Now let's turn that into actual code, which is simple:

```
var animStep = 0;
ANIMATE = function(){
    if(animStep == 0){
        //First frame -- where 'Do this' glows, everything else has shadow
    }else if(animStep == 1){
        //Second frame -- where 'Do that' glows
    }else if(animStep == 2){
        //Third frame -- where 'then this' glows
    }else if(animStep == 3){
        //Last frame -- where 'then that' glows
    }
    animStep++;
    animStep = animStep == 4 ? 0 : animStep
    setTimeout(ANIMATE,1000);
}
ANIMATE();
```

This will make it animate, you just have to tell it what to do.

I made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P25ym/) that does something similar